# sql invalid identifier on join

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to learn JOINS but I can't get this one to work. Trying to join a second table to the first one to get the name of the division, the dname variable.

```
select e.COUNT(empID), e.SUM(salary), e.DID, d.dname
from employee e
right join division on e.DID=d.DID
group by DID
```

Comment: You need to provide an alias (`right join division d`...).

Comment: now the error message is "column ambiguously defined"

Comment: PLease dont SPAM tags, they are used to gather a relevant audience, if you abuse them, all you get is an angry crowd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select COUNT(e.empID), SUM(e.salary), e.DID, d.dname
from employee e
right join division d on e.DID=d.DID
group by e.DID, d.dname
```

Comment: thanks! worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You missed the alias `d` on `division` and on the Group, and the alias goes inside the function call on the select line

```
select COUNT(e.empID), SUM(e.salary), e.DID, d.dname
from employee e
right join division d on e.DID=d.DID
group by e.DID
```

Comment: when running this I get the error "not a GROUP BY expression"

Comment: WHat are you using MySQL or Oracle

Comment: Yea, the group by did look a little odd, try removing it and see if the query runs then

Comment: I'm using Oracle livesql. If i remove the group by it says "not a single-group group function"

Comment: Thats probably because you have 2 non-amalgamation columns in the select and only one in the group by

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210320/not-a-single-group-group-function